# Control colors and shading of navigation circles in Beamer top line

Tags: beamer, color, navigation, mini-frames

I am preparing a presentation in Beamer using `\useoutertheme{miniframes}` and `\useinnertheme{circles}`, and my own modded version of the default colortheme.

I want to have a Frankfurt-like navigation bar in the top, but instead of setting a background color, I have an image providing the background for the top bar.

What I want is the current section title and subsection dots to be highlighted compared to the rest, like this:

> [image: Correct shading, but with bg color]

...except this only works when I declare a background colour for "section in head/foot". When I set `{bg=}` in that definition, it shades the active section and circles *darker* than the rest, which is the opposite of what I want:

> [image: correct bg, but now the shading is wrong]

If I set the `fg` to be completely white, then *everything* gets white, no shading of inactive regions. What I want is the shading on the first image with the background of the second image.

How can I achieve this?

---

### Edit: Minimal Working Example

Here's a minimal working example. To function, it needs a background image, I used [this background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubiwJ.jpg) from The Internetz(TM).

The code for a minimal working example is below.
There are 3 different options for `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}`; **option 1** produces correct background with all-white navigation with no shading, **option 2** provides correct background but wrong shading (the emphasized parts are darker on a dark background image), and **option 3** provides correct shading but sets a solid background color covering the image.

What I want is the background image of option 1 and 2, but the shading of the navigation items of option3.

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{baggrund.jpg}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
%\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=structure}%, bg=black} %opt.1
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=structure,fg=white!70!black} %opt.2
%\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=structure, bg=black} %opt.3
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white!80!blue}
\title{the title}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}

\section{S1}

\subsection{SS11}
\begin{frame}{Foo}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Bar}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\subsection{SS12}    
\begin{frame}{Baz}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Qux}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\section{S2}
\subsection{SS21}    
\begin{frame}{Buqz}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\subsection{SS22}
\begin{frame}{Bao}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Added an MWE now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To influence the colouring of the mini frames without changing the background colour of the header, you can use the beamer colour `mini frames` (by default, this just takes the colours from `section in head/foot`, which is why changing this colour also influences the mini frames):

```
\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{fg=white,bg=black}
```

However, this only solves half of your problem: while it gives correct colours for the mini frames itself, the section name colour is still wrong, as it is controlled by `section name in head/foot`:

[image: headline with mini frames highlighted/shaded as desired, but section name still in grey]

To fix this, you can patch the internal beamer commands to use the mini frame colour instead of the header colour for the section name:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}}{}{}
```

Together, this gives the desired result:

[image: headline with mini frames and section name highlighted/shaded as desired]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{baggrund.jpg}}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white!80!blue}

\setbeamercolor{mini frame}{fg=white,bg=black}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{mini frame}}{}{}

\title{the title}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}

\section{S1}

\subsection{SS11}
\begin{frame}{Foo}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Bar}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\subsection{SS12}    
\begin{frame}{Baz}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Qux}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\section{S2}
\subsection{SS21}    
\begin{frame}{Buqz}
    Some text
\end{frame}

\subsection{SS22}
\begin{frame}{Bao}
    Some text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Now that I see your answer, I think I misread the OP's intent and my answer doesn't really solve the problem (yours does). I'll delete mine.